# XSD Validating - Regular Expression

Tags: xml, regex, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm really "noob" with XSD, but I'm doing my  best.

I have this XML:

```
<nombre_completo xmlns:xsi="xxxx "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="nombre_completo.xsd">
  <nombre>Jame Ruiz</nombre>
  <apellido1>Sancho</apellido1>
  <apellido2>Vera</apellido2>
</nombre_completo>
```

And This XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="nombre_completo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="nombre" type="verificar_nombre"/>
        <xs:element name="apellido1" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="apellido2" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="verificar_nombre">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z]*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

All I Want its to Validate the name part. With a For Example Composed name: Miguel Angel, Jaime Ruiz. Or Just a Single Name like "Ramon" or "John".

I have tried:

```
[a-zA-Z]* [a-zA-Z]?
```

But nothing.

Comment: Your using `[a-zA-Z]` would reject my name, and my brother's name, and a name like Gabriel García Márquez.

Comment: Could you explain WHY you want to reject valid names such as "Gabriel García Márquez" or "Gus O'Donnell"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[a-zA-Z]* [a-zA-Z]` can accept nothing and one letter in front.
 so you need something like this

```
[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]*
```

This will give any combination of letters but can't be empty

```
 [a-zA-Z]+
```

plus this that will give you empty or any combination of letters.

```
[a-zA-Z]*
```

Comment: LoKuzt Thanks for you answer, but thats not the problem.

I want to validate the XML in the case of a 

- Single Name F.Ex: "Lokuzt"
- Composed Name F.Ex: "Lokuzt Rocks"

Comment: @user2402666 It seems to me that what Lokuzt is suggesting would do what you want. In case Lokuzt's answer was not verbose enough: `<xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]*"/>`